# What exactly does the "View Source code" of a web page reveal?

Tags: web, browser

So I know that every browser gives us an option to view source code of any page we visit. What I want to know is , why is the source code public? How much of the actual code does it reveal.

If it tells us everything that the programmer coded , wouldnt it be easy to copy any web page?

I want to know, What can be learnt from the sorce code that the browser shows us, and what we cant get to know from it.

I hope Im clear with my question, Thank you for the time. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

It shows all the client-side code. So all HTML, CSS and Javascript are visible. It has to be visible because that's how web pages are rendered by the browser - that's the essential information to show a web page. But view source does not show server-side scripts like Python or PHP code that is executed by the server before the code is served to the client. There's no way to see the server-side scripts.

One of the things that keeps people from copying is Copyright laws. But it is often useful to see how other websites implement their HTML and CSS.